# In Firebase hosting - what does the "usage" tab means?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have deployed my site with Firebase using my customed domain.
I checked my db usage and it seems fine (couple of megas) but then I go to the hosting section and then the usage tab and see almost 1GB downloads, do you know what the downloads in the hostage section means?

Answer (score 3):

It means that almost 1GB of data was downloaded from Firebase Hosting in your project.

If this is higher than you expected, you might want to check for the size of your files. Do you have any images? How big are those? How much data will each client read from Firebase Hosting? How many clients do you have? If you have a few large files that everyone loads, it adds up quickly.

Comment: First of all thank you! yes it is much more than I expected, I have 1 photo served (400KB) and one compiled code file that is 1MB which is weird since I don't have much code (maybe 'import * from firebase' is the problem?). I guess that it could add up to more than 1GB. Do you have any recommendations? thanks!

Comment: If you want to reduce your bundle size, I'd recommend searching for tutorials/answers on that topic.